# How to set optional parameter for int type variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have two variable StatusTypeTestID  and StatusTestID  want to set them as optional in where clause as like bellow,but optional option not work for int variable.

**Note:** default value for int variable is 0

```
DECLARE @StatusTypeTestID as int
SET @StatusTypeTestID = 1

DECLARE @StatusTestID as int
SET @StatusTestID = 0

select *
from LiveCustomerStatus
where (StatusType=@StatusTypeTestID
  and (Status = @StatusTestID or @StatusTestID is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were already trying, you can check if your parameters have been set as null or if they match the correspondent field.

This way you can leave a parameter as null if you want it to be optional, not affecting the result.

```
select *
from LiveCustomerStatus
where     (@StatusTypeTestID is null or StatusType=@StatusTypeTestID)    
      and (@StatusTestID is null     or Status = @StatusTestID)  
option(recompile)
```

I have added a option(recompile) clause that will force SQL Server to recompile the query at every execution. This way it will use the appropriate indexes to optimize it depending of the value of the parameters (wether they are null or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can comment both set statements and below query will work:

```
    select * from LiveCustomerStatus
    where (@StatusTypeTestID is null or StatusType=@StatusTypeTestID) 
    and (@StatusTestID is null or Status = @StatusTestID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE Statement in WHERE clause :

```
   SELECT *
   FROM LiveCustomerStatus
   WHERE StatusType = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@StatusTypeTestID,'') = '' THEN 
                                StatusType ELSE @StatusTypeTestID END
       AND Status = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@StatusTestID,'')= '' THEN Status ELSE  
         @StatusTestID  END
```